# Opendaylight snapshot repo has a version number attached to the artifacts

Tags: git, maven, opendaylight

Opendaylight snapshot repo has files with a wrong version number attached
http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/yangtools/concepts/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/

for example the above location contains files with version number as 
concepts-0.8.0-20160215.182615-501 instead of concepts-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT due to this maven is not able to find the dependencies.

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an proxy issue. Thanks for the help.